# How to deploy a Spring Boot application on Weblogic 12c (12.1.3)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, weblogic

I'm trying to deploy a simple Spring Boot application on Weblogic 12c (12.1.3), in a developer environment it does work perfectly. 
However when need to repackage it in a war and to attach it to an earand this does not seem to deploy correctly.

This is the stacktrace:

```
<Nov 23, 2016 6:15:13 PM CET> <Error> <Munger> <BEA-2156200> <Unable to load descriptor weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader@6964c078 finder: weblogic.utils.classloaders.CodeGenClassFinder@5715556 annotation: my-app-ear@/WEB-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.6.jar!/META-INF/web-fragment.xml of module /my-app. The error is weblogic.descriptor.DescriptorException: Unmarshaller failed
```

Any input will be very welcome. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your application.java ( main  class)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Spring Boot [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html#howto-weblogic),

> To deploy a Spring Boot application to WebLogic you must ensure that
>   your servlet initializer directly implements WebApplicationInitializer
>   (**even if you extend from a base class that already implements it**).

For Example,

Change this,

```
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
```

to

```
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
```

**NOTE:** SpringBootServletInitializer **already** implements WebApplicationInitializer, but you **need** to do it again.

As of now,I don't know Why.

```
public abstract class SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
```

From Spring [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot/1.0.2.RELEASE/org/springframework/boot/context/web/SpringBootServletInitializer.java) code,

Answer (score 1):

You need to do 2 things:

1. On your weblogic 12.1.3 instance, upgrade your JPA api and add the hibernate 5 implementation
2. In you web app, make sure what dependencies you have and that they do not overlap with the ones already provisioned under Weblogic classloader.

I have details the steps here:

http://javagoogleappspot.blogspot.be/2018/05/make-your-spring-boot-20-compatible.html