# Springboot application deployment on weblogic server via jdeveloper 12.2.1.4 IDE

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to deploy Springboot application on weblogic server through jdeveloper 12c and getting below error in parsing the main application class:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopedProxyMode cannot be cast to org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopedProxyMode

Kindly help me for the configuration needed in springboot application dpeloyment on weblogic server.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to improve the quality of your question. Please share a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: WebLogic ships with its own spring version. Change classloading or prefer classes from the war for `org.springframework`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40770784/how-to-deploy-a-spring-boot-application-on-weblogic-12c-12-1-3/50411323 and especially see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56542681/how-to-deploy-a-spring-boot-application-to-weblogic-12-2-1-3-0-without-deploy-a